# How to get String.Format not to parse {0}

Tags: c#, code-generation, string.format

I am writing a code generation tool that frequently will have lines like

```
StringBuilder sp = new Stringbuilder();
sp.AppendFormat("        public {0}TextColumn()\n", className);
sp.AppendLine("        {"
sp.AppendLine("            Column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();");
sp.AppendFormat("            Column.DataPropertyName = \"{0}\";\n", columnName);
```

However the issue I am having is when I run in to a line like this.

```
sp.AppendFormat("return String.Format(\"{0} = '{0}'\", cmbList.SelectedValue);", columnName);
```

I want the first `{0}` to turn in to whatever the value of columnName is but I want the seccond `{0}` to be left alone so the internal `String.Format` will process it correctly.

How do I do this?

Comment: By the way, are you aware of the T4 engine for code generation included in Visual Studio?

Comment: @0xA3 No I am not, does it work with the rt.click "Run Custom Tool"? That is what I am writing the code generation stuff for.

Comment: These http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/customtoolsexp.aspx are the custom tools I am referring to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use double curly braces:

```
string result = string.Format("{{Ignored}} {{123}} {0}", 543);
```

Answer (score 7):

Curly braces can be escaped by using two curly brace characters. The documentation of [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) states:

> To specify a single literal brace character in format, specify two leading or trailing brace characters; that is, "{{" or "}}".

In your example that would be

```
sp.AppendFormat("return String.Format(\"{0} = '{{0}}'\",cmbList.SelectedValue);", 
    columnName);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sp.AppendFormat("return String.Format(\"{0} = '{{0}}'\", cmbList.SelectedValue);", columnName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use "{{0}}". This will result in the string "{0}"

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format(\"{0} = '{{0}}'\",
```