# how to get a String with String.Format to execute?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, string.format

I have a little chunk of code (see below) that is returning the string:

```
string.Format("{0}----{1}",3,"test 2");
```

so how do I get this to actually "Execute"? To run and do the format/replacement of {0} and {1}?

My Code snippet:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{0}----{1}\",");
sb.AppendFormat(ReturnParamValue(siDTO, "siDTO.SuggestionItemID,siDTO.Title"));
string sbStr = "=string.Format(\""+sb.ToString()+");";
```

yes, ReturnParamValue gives the actually value of the DTO.

Anyways, I've taken a look at the following (but it doesn't say how to execute it:
[How to get String.Format not to parse {0}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319896/how-to-get-string-format-not-to-parse-0)

Maybe, I just should put my code snippet in a method. But, what then?

Comment: can you edit your code?  im having a hard time really understanding what you are after.

Comment: I think the tags are wrong; are you looking to do this in java or C#?

Comment: The java tag was obviously wrong (added by another user, not the OP), so I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you including String.Format in the string itself?

If you're looking for a generic "let me evaluate this arbitrary expression I've built up in a string" then there isn't a simple answer.

If, instead, you're looking at how to provide the parameters to the string from a function call, then you've got yourself all twisted up and working too hard.

Try something like this, based on your original code:

```
string result
    = string.Format(
        "{0}----{1}",
        ReturnParamValue(siDTO, "siDTO.SuggestionItemID,siDTO.Title"));
```

Though, this won't entirely work since your original code seems to be only providing a single value, and you have two values in your format string - the `{0}` will be replaced with the value from your function, and `{1}` left unchanged.

What output are you expecting?

Does your `ReturnParamValue()` function try to return both the label and the value in a single string? If it does, and if they're comma separated, then you could try this:

```
var value = ReturnParamValue(siDTO, "siDTO.SuggestionItemID,siDTO.Title"));
var pieces = string.Split(',');
string result
    = string.Format( "{0}----{1}", pieces[0], pieces[1]);
```

Though this is seriously working too hard if `ReturnParamValue()` is a method you control.

**Update Fri 6 August**

Check out the declaration for `string.Format()` [as shown on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx):

```
public static string Format(
    string format,
    params Object[] args
)
```

Unlike the special casing you might have seen in C for `printf()`, there's nothing special or unusual about the way `string.Format()` handles multiple parameters. The key is the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword, which asks the compiler to provide a little *"syntactic sugar"* where it combines the parameters into an array for you.

Key here is that the wrapping doesn't happen if you're already passing a single `object[]` - so if you wanted to, you could do something like this:

```
object[] parameters 
    = ReturnParamValues(siDTO, "siDTO.SuggestionItemID,siDTO.Title");
string result
    = string.Format("{0}----{1}----{2}", parameters);
```

Though, if I saw something like this in any codebase I maintained, I'd be treating it as a code-smell and looking for a better way to solve the problem.

Just because it's *possible* doesn't mean it's *advisable*. YMMV, of course.

Comment: as for the 2nd - BINGO!!! The only question: Is there a way to make pieces[0], pieces[1] dynamic? Hence, I don't ned to make a code change when there are 3 pieces? Personally, I don't think so.

Comment: Bevan - THanks for all your help. Talked over with the boss and I'm going to try the following: (1) Use Reflection to get the Values in Parameter (2) Put the params in an array (3) Loop through the params and replace the string with the value that I got in step 1. 

Keep your fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can execute it. Java is not really a interpreted language.

You may make use of scripting languages (which can even embed in your Java app as I know, start from JDK6) for such purpose, like Groovy

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegEx to parse the three parameters out of the string, and then pass them to a real, actual string.Format method :-)

Comment: That aside, I think the thing you're looking for is an "expression evaluator" so you could Google for that, once the aforementioned language debate is settled...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is something like this:

```
string sbStr = string.Format("{0}----{1}", siDTO.SuggestionItemID, siDTO.Title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didn't understand your question completely, but it sounds like you need to format a format-string. If that's true you could maybe try something like this:

```
int width = 5;
string format = String.Format("{{0,{0}}}----{{1,{0}}}", width);
string result = String.Format(format, "ab", "cd");
```

So the trick is simply to escape the `{` or `}` by using a double `{{` or `}}`.